# add ssh to exiting ubuntu failed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I forgot to add ssh key but I've created my server (ubuntu)

then I want to add my ssh to it, I did

`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"`

Then I do `cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

why am I not seeing anything? I tried to reaccess my server still prompt me for password.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the ssh-copy-id,it's more simple and useful

```
ssh-copy-id root@xxxxxxx
```

Comment: this is easy, yeah thank you!